# Alternative way for hiding corners of nested elements to using `overflow: hidden`?

Tags: html, css

When I set `overflow: hidden` on the container element in the example, the corners vanish, but the flex-items lose their height and shrink down if there's not enough vertical space.
Is there an alternative way to hide the corners or an additional setting to make the elements keep their height?

**Edit** Some more explanation what I am trying to achieve. My 'setup':

1. navigation element with 100% height of window and 40% "responsive width"
2. container element inside nav with border-radius
3. flex-items inside container with `flex-wrap: wrap` and background

My goal:

- To remove the background of the flex-items that is currently visible at the corners outside of the containers border-radius.

Is there a way to achieve this via CSS only?

Solutions I thought of / tried:

- giving the container `overflow:hidden` hides the corner of the flex-items, but they shrink down if there's not enough vertical space
- setting only `overflow-x: hidden` seems to set `overflow-y: auto` and a vertical scrollbar appears which should not happen
- setting the border radius on the flex-items in the 'corner positions' is no options, since the positions vary due to responsive container width and `flex-wrap`
- removing the `height` or setting `min-height` of the navigation solves the problem of the items losing their height. But then the Navigation has no scrollbar anymore and the content at the bottom of the navigation leaves the screen if there's not enough space

This is how the result should look like
[image: This image shows what I'm looking for]

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;  
}

#spacer {
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid darkmagenta;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  border-radius: 20px;
  /* overflow: hidden; */
}

.flex-item {
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="flex-item">All</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Adjective</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Adverb</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Conjunction</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Noun</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Number</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Preposition</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Pronoun</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Verb</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

This is a javascript version which would achieve what I'm looking for, but I still hope there's something I'm missing to do this with CSS only?

```js
document.body.onresize = setBorderRadius;

function setBorderRadius() {
  let r = "var(--border-radius)"
  let flexItems = [...document.getElementsByClassName("flex-item")];
  flexItems.forEach(item => item.style.borderRadius = "0")

  let topTmp = 0
  const sortedByRows = flexItems.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let top = item.getBoundingClientRect().top
    if (top > topTmp) acc.push([item])
    else acc[acc.length - 1].push(item)
    topTmp = top
    return acc
  }, [])

  let firstRow = sortedByRows[0]
  let upperLeft = firstRow[0]
  let upperRight = firstRow[firstRow.length-1]
  
  let lastRow = sortedByRows[sortedByRows.length-1]
  let lowerLeft = lastRow[0]
  let lowerRight = lastRow[lastRow.length-1]
     
  upperLeft.style.borderTopLeftRadius = r
  upperRight.style.borderTopRightRadius = r
  lowerLeft.style.borderBottomLeftRadius = r
  lowerRight.style.borderBottomRightRadius = r
}

setBorderRadius();
```

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
  --border-radius: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;  
}

#spacer {
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid darkmagenta;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="flex-item">All</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Adjective</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Adverb</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Conjunction</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Noun</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Number</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Preposition</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Pronoun</div>
      <div class="flex-item">Verb</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "corners" here? Do you mean that your problem is the way the orange flex-item blocks have square corners while the container has rounded corners? Because `overflow` won't solve that problem, I don't think - you'll need to set a `border-radius` on the flex-items. Also, the flex-items may be shrinking because they inherit `overflow: hidden` from the parent container. But mostly: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @JohnP I added some more explanation to my question

Answer (score 1):

```
.flex-item:first-child {
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 40px 40px;
 border: 2px solid orange;
 background: darkorange;
 border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.flex-item:last-child {
 flex-grow: 1;
 padding: 40px 40px;
 border: 2px solid orange;
 background: darkorange;
 border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px;
}
```

use these :first-child :last-child to keep you flex items in the border radius of the container

Comment: this would work if it was just one row of items, but the container has `flex-wrap: wrap` and the position of the items in the corner vary depending on the window width

Answer (score 0):

overflow-x: hidden, then it will work but with scroll.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the version with scrolling is no option

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `height: 100%` from `main` OR change it to `min-height: 100%` then `overflow: hidden` on `#container` will work.

Comment: Removing the `height` or setting `min-height` of main/nav solves the problem of the items losing their height. But then the Navigation has no scrollbar anymore and the content at the bottom of the navigation leaves the screen if there's not enough space

Answer (score 0):

If there's a way to do this in CSS3 I'm not smart enough to come up with it. The problem is, as you said, that `overflow: hidden` messes up how it's supposed to behave and `border-radius` on the first and last members of `.flex-item` won't work with every window size.

The problem with the `border-radius` approach is that, when the window size changes, you don't know which `.flex-item` elements need the `border-radius`. Which ones should have it depends on how many rows there are. I don't know of any way to determine this in pure CSS3, but it's not difficult in JavaScript. Using JS, you can get the width of the `#container` element and the width of the `.flex-item` elements. With that, you can determine the number of `.flex-item` elements per row (`#container` width / `.flex-item` width) and the number of rows (number of `.flex-item` elements / number of rows). Then you can set the `border-radius` on the first `.flex-item` element, the last in the first row, the first in the last row, and the last quite easily.

Because it's a script it will only run once, so you also need to make the above happen every time the window is resized. So we'll put the above in a function and set a resize event listener on the document body to that function. Because it's a function we'll have to call it on page load so that it sets the borders the first time.

So here's all that in code form (the HTML and CSS are the same as yours, just the JS is new). It's not particularly viewable in the tiny window here, so I'd recommend pasting it into another window.

```js
document.body.onresize = setBorderRadii;
function setBorderRadii() {
let r = "15";
  let flex_items = document.getElementsByClassName("flex-item");
  for (let i = 0; i < flex_items.length; i++) {
    flex_items[i].style.borderRadius = "0 0 0 0";
    flex_items[i].innerHTML = "flex item";
  }
  let items = flex_items.length;
  let containerWidth = document.getElementById("container").clientWidth;
  let flexWidth = flex_items[0].clientWidth;
  let rowSize = Math.floor(containerWidth / flexWidth);
  let rows = Math.ceil(items / rowSize);
  switch (rowSize) {
    case 1:
      flex_items[0].style.borderRadius = r + "px " + r + "px 0 0";
      flex_items[items - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 0 " + r + "px " + r + "px";
      break;
    case items - 1:
      flex_items[0].style.borderRadius = r + "px 0 0 0";
      flex_items[6].style.borderRadius = "0 " + r + "px 0 0";
      flex_items[items - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 0 " + r + "px " + r + "px";
      break;
    case items:
      flex_items[0].style.borderRadius = r + "px 0 0 " + r + "px";
      flex_items[items - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 " + r + "px " + r + "px 0";
      break;
    default:
      flex_items[0].style.borderRadius = r + "px 0 0 0";
      flex_items[rowSize - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 " + r + "px 0 0";
      flex_items[rowSize * (rows - 1)].style.borderRadius = "0 0 0 " + r +"px";
      flex_items[items - 1].style.borderRadius = "0 0 " + r + "px 0";
  }
}
setBorderRadii();
```

```css
html, body {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: scroll;  
}

#spacer {
  min-height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid darkmagenta;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.flex-item {
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 40px 40px;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  background: darkorange;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="spacer"></div>
    <div id="container">
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
      <div class="flex-item">flex item</div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

This should work even with different numbers of `.flex-item` elements as long as there's more than one.

The `r` variable in there determined the `border-radius` applied to the `.flex-item` elements. It's less than 20 to make sure there's no white space between the corner of the `#container` element and the corners of the `.flex-item` elements.

If you're not familiar with using JS in your HTML docs, you use the `<script>` tag. You can Paste the whole code between the tags like this:

```
<script>
/* code here */
</script>
```

or use a `.js` file with the script inside and a script tag like this:

```
<script src=" {script file location} "></script>
```

Make sure to place the script element after the relevant HTML elements, or else it will not work (if it's before them it will try to perform action on elements that don't exist yet, rendering an error).

Comment: Thanks for the effort of writing the javascript version. Since it was already complicated enough the example I gave was actually simplified and the elements won't all have the same width... I added a picture to the question and am still hoping for a CSS solution. If I have to go with js, I'll probably set the radius with `elem.style.borderTopLeftRadius`, `elem.style.borderBottomRightRadius`, ... would maybe be not less code in the end (I guess all values would have to be reset at the beginning) but it would overall be easier to read

Comment: The element width is just used to figure out how many elements will be in each row  before the last, as they should keep constant width until then. It rounds the first element, the last, the last in the first row, and the one after the last in the second to last row, which is always the first in the last row but calculating position that way prevents errors from the variable width that comes with the elements per row not being constant all the way down. At the very least, this does work with the code you provided.

Comment: I'm sorry that my question wasn't precise enough and misleading, I'll try to avoid that in the future. I added a javascript version for the scenario with different element widths in case you're interested